# General Solution to Pseudo-Geometric Polynomial Product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, products

Is there a general, fixed number of operations simplification to the expression $$\prod_{i=0}^{n} (a+bx^i)$$ in the same vein as $$\prod_{i=0}^n ax^i = (\sqrt {a^2 x^n})^{n+1}$$

Comment: "Equation"?  Where's the equals sign?

Comment: First of all, your second equation is just a different way of writing $\prod_{i=0}^n ax^i = a^{n+1} x^{\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ Regarding the first equation IMHO, there is few hope to obtain a compact formula.

Comment: I understand now your second formula which, written under the form $\left[\prod_{i=0}^n (ax^i)\right]^{\tfrac{1}{n+1}} = \sqrt {a^2 x^n}$ expresses the geometric mean of $n+1$ consecutive terms of a geometric progression. And you want to know is there is a similar formula for an arithmetic-geometric progression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what we can do except developing the product as following : $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left(a+bx^{k}\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a^{n-k}b^{k}\sum_{1\leq i_{1}<\cdots <i_{k}\leq n}{x^{i_{1}+\cdots +i_{k}}}} $$ which is a generalisation of the binomial theoreme, thanks to it we can find the second result you gave by setting $ a=0 \cdot $

Comment: The first sum is then multiplied by the second sum? If not can you clarify?